# Is it possible to allocate text on the left, center and right of a line without a table?

Tags: html, css

I want to put some text on the left of my page, some on the center and some of the right. Like this:

```
Left                                       Center                                    Right
```

And I tried with that code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Title</TITLE>

    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <div>
            <p style = "float:left"> Left </p>
            <p style = "float:center; text-align: center;" > Center </p>
            <p style = "float:right"> Right </p>
        </div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

and it positions the different words correctly but in different lines. **I want that the three words will be on the same line.**

I also tried changing all paragraphs `<p>` to `<span>` and the three words are displayed in the same line but only the words `Left` and `Right` are positioned correctly. The word `Center` it is not displayed on the center, just following the word `Left`.

I saw that in some cases people do this with a table.

Is it possible to avoid it and get the same behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can someone explain me why it is being downvoted please?

Comment: Agreed - no idea why...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lambo477/L5rmsvqt/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p class="left-text col">Left Text</p>
    <p class="center-text col">Center Text</p>
    <p class="right-text col">Right Text</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333333%;
}

.left-text {
    text-align: left;
}

.center-text {
    text-align: center;
}

.right-text {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works properly and it is responsive. I like it ;)

Answer (score 2):

**[JSFIDDLE example](http://jsfiddle.net/7s0zLxkn/)**

```
<div>
    <p>Left</p>
    <p>Center</p>
    <p>Right</p>
</div>

div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

P.S. Keep in  mind the [flexbox support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

Answer (score -1):

That should help

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Title</TITLE>
        <style>
            .pos{
                width:33%;
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <div>
            <span class=pos align=left> Left </span>
            <span class=pos align=center> Center </span>
            <span class=pos align=right> Right </span>
        </div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Why do you put `width: 33%`? I suppose that you divide the screen in 3 parts but I am not secure...

Comment: the width of the parent is 100%
so if every child got 33%, then they will perfectly have the same width size